# How to create a dictionary with certain specific behaviour of values

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have two lists:

```
l1 = [['b', (1, 1)], ['b', (1, 2)], ['b', (1, 3)], ['a', (1, 5)],
      ['b', (2, 1)], ['b',(3, 1)]]

l2 = ['A','B','C']
```

How can I create a dictionary into this format?

```
dct = {'A': len(sublist1), 'B': len(sublist2), 'C' : len(sublist3)}
```

where

```
sublist1 = [['b', (1, 1)], ['b', (1, 2)], ['b', (1, 3)], ['a', (1, 5)]]
sublist2 = [['b', (2, 1)]]
sublist3 = [['b',(3, 1)]]
```

what will happen if my l1 is as given below:

```
ls1 = [[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 2)]]
```

then my output should be:

```
dct = {'A': len(sublist1), 'B': len(sublist2)}
```

where

```
sublist1 = [[(1, 1),(1, 2),(1, 3),(1, 4)]]
sublist2 = [[(2, 1),(2, 2),(2, 3)]]
```

Can the overall problem can be solved in generic way?

Comment: what determines why an element of `l1` should be a in `sublist`n?

Comment: @msw simple guess, I think element `e` of `l1` is in `sublistN` where `N = e[1][0]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
from itertools import groupby

key = lambda x: x[1][0]
lens = [len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(sorted(l1, key=key), key=key)]
dct = dict(zip(l2, lens))
```

I hope I've inferred correctly when I've assumed A match with 1, B with 2, and so on.

**Re: OP edit**

I don't know where the `(2, 3)` item in your `sublist2` comes from, I assume it's a mistake. Also, I assume the single element list `ls1` was in fact meant to be the direct container of the tuples, since using nested lists here serves no purpose. If so, here's my proposal for a generic solution:

```
from itertools import groupby
from string import ascii_uppercase

key = lambda x: x[0]
lens = [len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(sorted(l1, key=key), key=key)]
dct = dict(zip(ascii_uppercase, lens))
```

So, no big changes. The `zip` function will, when given arguments of unequal length, return a list with the same length as the shortest argument, and this behaviour suits us fine in this situation.

Keep in mind that if there are more than 26 different values of the first tuple element, then this solution will break, and simply disregard any values larger than the 26th.

Comment: This is what I had just come up with.

Comment: I wonder if creating a tuple instead of a list would be faster -- e.g. `lens = [len(tuple(g)) for k,g in ...]`.  It might be worth timing to find out ...

Comment: ls3 = [[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (2, 2)]]

Comment: what if I had default dictionary of lists d2 = deafultdict(list)?? how to do the last line of your code for d2?

Comment: @smazon09 See my updated answer. I hope I understood your update correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
groups = itertools.groupby(l1, lambda x: x[1][0])
dict(zip(l2, map(len, (list(list(g[1]) for g in groups)))))
```

results in

```
{'A': 4, 'B': 1, 'C': 1}
```

Comment: This only works if `l1` is sorted on `[1][0]` as it is in the question. If this is not the case, `sorted` must be used as in the answer by lazyr.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l1 = [['b', (1, 1)], ['b', (1, 2)], ['b', (1, 3)], ['a', (1, 5)], ['b', (2,
1)], ['b',(3, 1)]]
>>> dct = {'A': 0, 'B' : 0, 'C': 0}
>>> translation = {1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C'}
>>> for list_ in l1:
...     letter, tuple_ = list_
...     num1, num2 = tuple_
...     t = translation[num1]
...     dct[t] += 1
...
>>> dct
{'A': 4, 'C': 1, 'B': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [['b', (1, 1)], 
       ['b', (1, 2)],
       ['b', (1, 3)],
       ['a', (1, 5)],
       ['b', (2, 1)],
       ['b', (3, 1)]]  #test list

def mapping(x):
    """ convert 1 to A, 2 to B and so on """
    return chr(ord('A')+x-1)

dct = defaultdict(int)

for _, tple in lst:
    k, _ = tple
    dct[ mapping(k) ] += 1

print (dct) # defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'A': 4, 'C': 1, 'B': 1})
```

Answer (score -1):

I would have done this :

```
dct = dict((k, len([l for l in l1 if l[1][0] == i + 1]))
           for i, k in enumerate(l2))
```

Comment: "range() integer end argument expected, got list."

Comment: Yep, I made a mistake, this is enumerate()